# Restoring project file to previous version?

Tags: version-control, xcode5

I currently have an app that has two updates released. Can I restore my project so all my code, interface, plist settings and so on go back to how everything was in version 1.1 or 1.0? Are these previous versions stored somewhere possibly on itune connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you used source control ([Git](http://git-scm.com/book) is built in to Xcode now and is a dang good FREE source control system). You *might* get lucky if you used the [snapshots](http://umairsaeed.com/2011/01/12/snapshots-in-xcode/) feature in Xcode to take a snapshot of your code for each release, but it is NOT a replacement for real source control.

Comment: Wasn't looking forward to seeing that answer. Oh well thank for your help and ill look into using source control from now on.

Comment: Just thought of something - if you developed on 10.7+ or setup regular Time Machine backups, you should be able to get at older versions of your files. It'll take quite a bit of work though.